# How to get value of Interval between two characters value in a string with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a string like this:

```
$string = "OXOXXOOOOOOXOOOOOOOOOOXOOOOXOOXOOOOXOOOOOOOXXOOOOOOOOOOOXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOX"
```

I need to get the value of interval between every "X" (How many "O" are between every "X" also counting all the "O" before the first "X").

Does anybody know how to do this with powershell?
Thanks a lot for support

For a string like this:

```
$string = "OXOXXOOOOOOXOOOOOOOOOOXOOOOXOOXOOOOXOOOOOOOXXOOOOOOOOOOOXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOX"
```

The first part of the output should be something like this:

1;1;0;6;10;4;.... and so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-split` regex operator to split on any position immediately following an `X` (except for at the very end of the string), then count the length of each resulting substring and substract 1 for the `X` itself:

```
$intervals = $string -split '(?<=X)(?!$)' |ForEach-Object { $_.Length - 1 }
```

If the string might contain a trailing chunk of `O`'s with no `X`'s after it, change the final block to count the exact length after trimming for trailing `X`'s:

```
$intervals = $string -split '(?<=X)(?!$)' |ForEach-Object { $_.TrimEnd('X').Length }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what value the positive lookbehind and negative lookahead brings to the split? It appears that a simplistic `$string -split 'X' | ForEach-Object { $_.Length }` also produces the desired result.

Comment: with your method it also returns the number of 'O' after the last 'X' when the 'X' is the last characters

Comment: @sirtao You mean it returns the last chunk of O's after the last X if X _isn't_ the last character? I've added an alternative option that takes that into account :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I was actually replying to lit 's comment but I forgot to [at] him. Sorry for the confusion. I'm glad I made you think of a scenario myself didn't think of though :D

Comment: @sirtao best misunderstanding of the day, cheers! ^_^

Comment: @sirtao, you are right. How about `$string.TrimEnd('X') -split 'X' | ForEach-Object { $_.Length }`? It is a little (microseconds) faster. Not long enough to get a cup of coffee.

Comment: @lit Still wrong - if multiple segments at the end are X-only then you'll be hiding them all. In other words, your suggestion would produce `@(1)` instead of `@(1,0,0)` for `$string = 'OXXX'`

Comment: Ok, one more attempt. This is beginning to make the regex more readable, but it is still a bit faster. `($string[-1] -eq 'X' ? $string.Substring(0, $string.Length -1) : $string) -split 'X' | ForEach-Object {$_.TrimEnd('X').Length}` It would be nice if PowerShell could slice a `[string]` with the range operator. `$string[0..-1]`